# How to disable the new, annoying, MSDN orange "Change view" button?

Tags: firebug

I've tried using noscript on firefox but it doesn't help, is there any way to use firebug to disable this button?

Comment: How about a link to an example (for those of us that avoid MSDN like the plague)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a Greasemonkey script.

Answer (score 1):

With Firebug enabled (assuming Windows platform):

1. Right-click on the "Change View" button
2. Choose "Inspect Element" from the context menu
3. In the HTML tree in Firebug, click the DIV with an ID value of "ctl00_LwViewSwitcher1_ViewSwitcherButton" (if it's not already selected)
4. In the "Style" pane on the right, right-click on the ".LWVS_Button" style rule
5. Choose "New Property" from the context menu
6. Name the new property "display" and give it a value of "none"

Tada! No more button.

Of course, this isn't a permanent solution, but Firebug isn't designed to continually filter web pages on subsequent visits. For that you'd want Greasemonkey like Anthony Mills said, or something similar.